# In Android, where is the default directory when I write a file?

Tags: java, android, file-io

In a Java-based Android application on a production device (USB debugging is enabled, so I can adb shell), I wrote a file something like:

`BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("log.txt"));`

But I can't easily find the location of `log.txt`. Where can I find it?

And a follow-up question: what is a recommended directory for such writing a log/debug file?

Answer (score 1):

> Where can I find it?

You can't. Your code crashed, because you did not provide a fully-qualified path.

Use `File` objects pointing to valid locations on [internal storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2017/11/13/storage-situation-internal-storage.html) or [external storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2017/11/14/storage-situation-external-storage.html).

> what is a recommended directory for such writing a log/debug file?

Usually, we log to LogCat, using methods on the `Log` class.

Comment: Thanks! Yes, I was too newbie in the Android world. I'll provide a full path. A follow-up: the reason I want to write a file (instead of logcat) is because of the size. I need to dump 1MB data. That's why I was looking for dumping a file.

Comment: @Nullptr: Then you need to consider whether this logging is being done in production, whether the user should have access to it, are there privacy concerns, etc. External storage allows user access, but it also allows other apps to have access.

Comment: Thanks. We won't do that in production. It's only for testing/development. Unfortunately, Pixel XL doesn't have an external storage, and I can't do adb root. I'm trying to write to an internal storage.

Comment: @Nullptr: "Unfortunately, Pixel XL doesn't have an external storage" -- yes, it does. My answer included links to blog posts explaining what [internal storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2017/11/13/storage-situation-internal-storage.html) and [external storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2017/11/14/storage-situation-external-storage.html) are, including clearing up the misconception that external storage is an SD card.